# Exclude Specific model field with foreignkey relation from Django model Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have three table. Student, School, Result

```
class Student(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     school = models.Foreignkey(School)  

class School(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=225)

class Result(models.Model):
    student = models.Foreignkey(Student)
    marks = models.FloatField()
```

corresponding serializers for those models are like

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model = School
           fields = '__all__'

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      school = SchoolSerializer(read_only=True)
      class Meta:
            model =  student
            fields = '__all__'

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      student = StudentSerializer(read_only=True)
      class Meta:
           model = student
           fields = '__all__'
```

Whenever resultserializer call, i want studentSerializer should hide student address information. I have already tried to include exclude field as

```
exclude = ('student__address',)
```

from this [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) but this doesn't work as student__address is not a model field of result model. How to exclude that address field or hide it from serializer response.

Comment: Why not make a `class StudentAddressHiddenSerializer(StudentSerializer)` that hides the address, and then use that a a serializer for `student`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define new `ResultStudentSerializer`serializer which will be used only in `ResultSerializer`:

```
class ResultStudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      school = SchoolSerializer(read_only=True)
      class Meta:
            model =  student
            fields = '__all__'
            exclude = ('address',)

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      student = ResultStudentSerializer(read_only=True)
      class Meta:
           model = Result
           fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I am really sorry for this. I just totally forget about this.